# Why does PhpStorm not suggest a variable name in a string?

Tags: phpstorm

Given the fantastic coding guidance PhpStorm offers I am a bit confused regarding the lack of variable name suggestions for variables used in strings.

```
$variable = "something";

// A:
$variable;

// B:
$str = "$variable";

// C:
$str = "{$variable}";
```

In case A PhpStorm suggests variables, not in cases B and C though.

As this is a very straightforward feature and Eclipse offers it too, I guess I have to adjust my configuration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works fine in both cases (verified in 2.1.4), however automatic completion is not enabled in order not to distract you from the actual string editing and you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to invoke code completion:

[image: code completion on ctrl+space]

Comment: Ahaaaa ... Ctrl+Space ... there you go! Thanks!